# ros electric gpsd_client error

Tags: ros, gpsd-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

currently gpsd_client did not work any more ;-

```
MockBot$ rosrun gpsd_client gpsd_client _port:=2947

netlib_connectsock() returns socket on fd 9
[ INFO] [1321344855.149877424]: GPSd opened
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::math::rounding_error> >'
  what():  Error in function boost::math::round<d>(d): Value nan can not be represented in the target integer type.
Abgebrochen
```

gpsd is running:

```
MockBot$ sudo lsof -i :2947
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gpsd    3466 nobody    4u  IPv4  93755      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:gpsd (LISTEN)
gpsd    3466 nobody    5u  IPv6  93756      0t0  TCP ros:gpsd (LISTEN)
```

I've updated ros-electric with apt-get to the last version...

Any idea ?

Cheers

Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11935/ros-electric-gpsd_client-error/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the same error when using an UBOX gps.. the problem was that the gps doesn't publish the time as requested by the gpsd_client.

To solve it you have to pass a parameter to disable the time from gps

here is the command line i use to start gpsd_client

$ rosrun gpsd_client gpsd_client _host:=localhost _port:=2947 _use_gps_time:=false

and it should work

Regards

Mario

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

process[gpsd_client-7]: started with pid [1697]

:-)

New release from git and your suggestion _use_gps_time:=false works out of the box !!!

GREAT!
Thanks and special greetings from Hamburg
Cheers
Christian

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-05-24**:
Please use the comment section instead of answering. The answers are not displayed in chronological order so it can get confusing. Thanks!